# How can I increase the audio volume?

Tags: sound

I changed my OS to Ubuntu from Windows 10. In Windows 10, the sound volume is good, but in Ubuntu the volume is decreased.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Can you not turn the sound up?

Comment: I'm using 20.04. I can turn the sound up. But the sound volume decrease after installing

Comment: If you can simply turn up the volume I am not seeing a problem.

Comment: so you need help from the comunity to adjust the volume of your system?

Answer (score 0):

Leftclick on the speaker-icon. To the rightside of the slidebar you see 3 horizontal stripes. Click on them, you can the increase your max. volume to 150%.